# Iptables configuration in CentOS for GCM commands

Tags: iptables, google-cloud-platform

I am planning to enable iptables for my CentOS VM. Have configured the below rules. But for GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) commands it fails to receive reply from GCM server. If i disable iptables it works perfectly.

```
iptables -F
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5228 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5229 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5230 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
```

Can someone guide me on the exact port for GCM to work? I read it in many places that its 5228,5229 and 5230 but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to connect a service which is listening on ports 5228, 5229, and 5230, the related `iptables` rules should be `--sport <port>`, not `--dport <port>`, because you're looking to accept packets coming *from* the service to your machine, and those ports will have a source port of whatever port you're connecting to, and a destination port of whatever random high port was chosen for the outgoing connection.

The more usual way to do this kind of thing is just to allow all related/established connection traffic back in, and let conntrack deal with the tricky bits.  Given that you're running a default-accept `OUTPUT` chain, I assume you're not overly concerned about running a tight policy, so I can't think of any reason you'd not want to run your return traffic via conntrack.